# Statistics wording question

Tags: probability, self-study, bayesian, posterior, references

I am reading a statistical procedure trying to figure out and understand what's going on.

The statement says "Compute the posterior on $\mu$."

Does this mean compute $p(\mu)$?   Does this mean "Compute the posterior probability of $\mu$." (see how "of" replaces "on")?

Immediately before in the reading, $\mu$ is allowed to take on multiple values.

Maybe there is a statistical wording/vocabulary convention I'm unaware of that would make this make more sense to me?

This is not critical, but I am just trying to understand better. If anyone could help me or point me to a resource that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mu$ is discrete, they mean "compute the posterior probabilities" for $\mu.$ If $\mu$ is continuous, they mean compute the posterior density function. If you are using the notation $p(\mu)$ to mean a probability mass function or probability density function, then yes you should compute $p(\mu).$

Comment: I was the one who originally posted this question.   Thank you for your response.  It makes some sense!  I appreciate it. As a matter of fact,mu  *does* take on a set of discrete values!

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes the concepts in probability are overtaken by notation and/or terminology.